# can ozone run upwards through a silicon tube and exit against gravity?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, gas-laws

I want to get ozone into an attic where rats are running around. For some reason, the attic is inaccessible to us.  I ordered a bubbling ozone unit. We will drill a hole into the attic and run the silicon ozone tube (without the bubbler) through a small-diameter PVC pipe and then run that pipe with the silicon tube sticking about an inch or half-inch out of the pipe up into the attic. So the ozone tube will be held in place and will exit the silicon tube straight up into the the attic air.  (The bubbler won't be attached, of course.) The ozone unit will be located inside of the house, so the actual $\ce{O3}$ will have to leave the unit and run upwards into the attic.

**My question is**: Can the ozone run upwards that way and exit the unit, against gravity, instead of downwards out of the unit, with gravity?

I want to get enough ozone into the attic air to cause the rats to want to leave the area.  We can't get into the attic to set traps and we would prefer not to kill the rats, rather to make the attic an undesirable space for them to occupy.  I figured we would run the unit every four hours for half an hour.  We want the ozone to exit into open space instead of from a silicon tube laying on the attic floor, so at least it will leave in air and have someplace to move around.  But there won't be a fan to move the $\ce{O3}$ around in the attic once it exits the tube. It will exit the tube into unmoving air...?

Comment: I am not at all certain that ozone is either an effective rodenticide or safe to use in any environment that is not hermetically sealed. I would *absolutely* not do this. Rely on professional pest controllers.

Comment: The OP explicitly prefers rather "rodentorepelent". But I would advice against this usage of ozone as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ozone producers do not produce pure ozone ( if they did, they would be chemical weapons ). They provide just air somewhat enriched with ozone, with density negligibly higher than pure air.(*)

Changes of "ozone in air" temperature have much higher impact on its density than achievable ozone content. Therefore, in density context, consider the outgoing gas just as if it was air.

If the output is warmer than the targeted air, it will climb up. If it is colder, it will sink down. In any case, there would be significant mixing by diffusion or air circulation.

So in summary, expect ozone to be propagated to all directions, desired ones and not desired ones.

Much stronger effect that flow dissipation has relatively fast ozone decaying due its reactivity, disappearing in typically dozens of minutes.

---

(*) Note that human nose is very sensitive for ozone content, with detection threshold at ratio near 1 : 10 000 000.